# Babel giving Plugin/Preset did not return an object after adding @babel/helper-annotate-as-pure

Tags: babeljs

I've recently added `@babel/helper-annotate-as-pure` to my list of babel plugins:

```js
    require('babel-plugin-macros'),
    require('@babel/helper-annotate-as-pure').default,
    require('babel-plugin-dev-expression'),
    [
      require('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties').default,
      {
        loose: true,
      },
    ],
    [require('@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators').default, { legacy: true }],
    require('@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator').default,
    [
      require('@babel/plugin-transform-runtime').default,
      {
        corejs: false,
        helpers: true,
        version: require('@babel/runtime/package.json').version,
        regenerator: true,
        useESModules: moduleFormat === 'esm',
      } as RuntimeOptions,
    ],
    require('@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import').default,
    require('@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining').default,
    require('@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator').default,
    isDevelopment && require.resolve('react-refresh/babel'),
```

I previously used `'babel-plugin-annotate-pure-calls'` but after adding the plugin I continually get the same error at different points:

```
Plugin/Preset did not return an object
```

If I comment out the plugin, everything works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@babel/helper-annotate-as-pure` is a helper utility module that is part of Babel itself, it is not a plugin, so it cannot be used in the `plugins` array. All plugins in the `@babel` namespace start with `plugin-` in their name.

You'd have to see if `babel-plugin-annotate-pure-calls`, the original plugin you used, works properly.